# Sidekiq job running slow in parallel

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sidekiq

I am running a sidekiq job that has many queries to a postgres 4.7 database. When It is run in parallel, it runs about 3 times as slow because of some sort of backup. When running a profile, the entire job dialates and there is no bottleneck. It is run on every row in a csv, visits each cell, and creates a database entry for that cell. The overall structure is the following:

```
def perform(row)
    ActiveRecord.base.transaction do
       row.cells.each do |cell|
          # db ops for cell
       end
       # fetch metadata for row from api and write
    end
end
```

The job is not threadsafe, and runs into upsert isues as some cells share values with other rows. I also am seeing the runtime mysteriously skyrocket from about 2.5 seconds per job to about 15 seconds per job when there are multiple running in parallel. I am not sure if it is a locking issue, or if the job is simply waiting for processing time on a thread. Honestly, I'm pretty much stumped and was wondering what approach I could take to finding the source of the error.